# Slick slider + Thumbnails в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, slider, slick.js

Планирую использовать slick slider в модальном окне (плагин Remodal).
Посмотреть можно [тут](http://dev.remxpert.ru) в разделе "Наши работы".
Проблема в том, что при первом открытии модального окна наблюдается странное поведение слайдера, после нажатия F5 при открытом модальном окне все отображается нормально + появляются thumbnail навигация по слайдам. В чем проблема?

Comment: насчет слик слайдера я не знаю, но, может у него есть какой-то метод типа: `update()`? По идее должен быть, при открытии попапа просто вызывайте метод `update()` (или какой-нибудь), чтобы слайдер переинициализировался и работал как надо) (`.slick('refresh');` вроде)

Comment: посмотрел все методы, ничего подобного не нашел.
Попробовал реализовать в теле страницы - все отлично. Действительно нужна дополнительная инициализация, сижу пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Сейчас понимаю что связанно это с тем, что изначально у модального окна display: none. Т.е. по идее slick slider не может адекватно рассчитать ширину для отображения. По-этому он и работает исправно только после F5

Comment: для модалок легче самому описать слайды, чем использовать слик

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, в общем я близок к разгадке.
Добавил инициализацию слайдера при открытии модального окна:

```
$(document).on('opened', '.remodal', function (){
    $('.slick_slider').slick({
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        fade: true,
        asNavFor: '.slick_slider_nav'
    });
    $('.slick_slider_nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        asNavFor: '.slick_slider'
    });
});
```

Дело осталось за малым - проскакивает слегка изображение. Кто что подскажет?